# Changing drawn function after limit when using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have two functions `y = x` and `y = 1`. I want to plot them by using ggplot2 so that first function is drawn when x[0,1] and second function when x[1,3]

I couldn't figure out how to set limits for the individual function. I can only limit drawn area or data for both functions.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 3)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) x, colour="red") + stat_function(fun=function(x) 1, colour="blue")
```

[image]

So I want that before `x = 1` only red line is drawn and after `x = 1` only blue line is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
f1 <- function(x) x
f2 <- function(x) 1
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 3)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) ifelse(x <= 1, f1(x), NA), colour="red") +
  stat_function(fun=function(x) ifelse(x >= 1, f2(x), NA), colour="blue")
```

[image]

Or maybe you want just one line with one color, so you can try:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 3)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) ifelse(x <= 1, f1(x), f2(x)), colour="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! One color solution seems to be better(no gap).